# Drag and Drop Operation Resets the Undo Stack for a Textbox

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, textbox, undo

I have an issue with the Undo stack being destroyed when doing a drop operation on a TextBox.

Reflector didn't give any insights on how the TextBox handles the Undo stack in this state.

I also see no way to control this Undo stack at all, that it is completely internal. I've seen the MS folks say much the same over at the MSDN forums.

Anyone have any ideas on how to prevent a drop action on a Textbox from destroying its Undo history stack?

Comment: Is this for dropping text from another textbox? Or is this for any drag / drop operation. Also, do you know if the drag events fire when text is dropped? Could you intercept those, cancel the native drop, and then append the text yourself?

Comment: The drop is a file from an explorer window or the like. We do catch the file name and append those to the the text manually. It still hoses the undo stack.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite answering your question, but you could manage your own undo stack for the textbox. There are a number of Undo frameworks to help in this area, or you could roll your own if this is the only textbox that needs custom undo.

I happen to maintain one of these undo frameworks on Codeplex. The "[Monitored Undo Framework"](http://muf.codeplex.com/) watches for changes to the data, stores the changed values, and provides simple methods for undoing / redoing these changes.

I have looked at the implementation of the TextBox in reflector too. The code is not trivial and appears to traverse a pretty large codebase for text handling. As far as I know, the only knob available for tweaking a textbox's Undo is to turn undo on / off. Beyond that, it seems to be a black box.